# Defaultdict Heapq is it possible?

Tags: python, heap, defaultdict

I love collections.defaultdict in Python. But I'd really like to use it with a heapq heap, which considering the Python heapq implementation is built on lists i thought should be possible. But I see no way to do it

```
d = defaultdict(list)

d[1].append((1, "Dog"))
```

e.g

if append was heappush. Is there a way?

Comment: Maybe `heapq.heappush(d[1], (1, 'Dog'))`?

Comment: Heapq uses any external list as a storage, you dont need to couple a heap and container explicitly, so @vaultah is right.

Comment: Of course. Duh! Thanks vaultah

Comment: I think @vaultah is answering the question as asked, but I suspect there's more to it. (I can't see what purpose the defaultdict is serving there.) Could you say more about the exact behavior you're trying to produce? (edit: or maybe not... hm. So the goal is just to have an empty heap as the default value for each key?)

Comment: I was thinking it had to be defaultdict(heapq.heapify([])). But that runs into KeyError. defaultdict(list) works perfectly. I'm not sure I completely understand why though.